# Passing props values to component

Tags: vue.js, properties, components

I have this component: InputField.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full">
    <label class="sr-only" :for="name"></label>
    <input
      :placeholder="label"
      :name="name"
      class="border-b border-black w-full appearance-none w-full py-4 px-3 text-grey-darker leading-tight"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'label', /* <--------- Always prints default */
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'name', /* <--------- Always prints default */
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
}
</script>
```

And this is how i'm using it from another component:

```
<inputField :label="Hola" :name="nombre" />
```

But `label` and `name` are allways the default values defined in the component declaration,

Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: Hi Toni, check out my answer, hope it's clear enough, you almost had it right it was just syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to capitalize on the snippet done by Utlime but there a lot of problems in that answer, in fact you must NOT take out the ":" as it is the thing that binds it as props and actually will let multiple instances of the component to have their "own" props states, just call it like `:aProp="'something'"` if you are using hard coded values, if you're passing a variable then go with `:aProp='variable'`
The correct example would be:

```js
Vue.component('InputField', {
  template: `
    <div class="w-full">
    <label class="sr-only" :for="name"></label>
    <input
      :placeholder="label"
      :name="name"
      class="border-b border-black w-full appearance-none w-full py-4 px-3 text-grey-darker leading-tight"
    />
  </div>
  `,

  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'label', /* <--------- No longer prints default if props are given */
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'name',
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-field :label="'Hola'" :name="'nombre'"></input-field>
  <input-field :label="'Que tal Toni'" :name="'toni'"></input-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `:`

```
<inputField label="Hola" name="nombre" />
```

[Passing Static or Dynamic Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props)

```js
Vue.component('InputField', {
  template: `
    <div class="w-full">
    <label class="sr-only" :for="name"></label>
    <input
      :placeholder="label"
      :name="name"
      class="border-b border-black w-full appearance-none w-full py-4 px-3 text-grey-darker leading-tight"
    />
  </div>
  `,

  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'label', /* <--------- Always prints default */
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'name', /* <--------- Always prints default */
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-field label="Hola" name="nombre" /></input-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I needed to remove the : if i was passing a static value, thanks!